# How do I access safari reading list with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a simple app that will show a random article from a user's safari reading list, but couldn't find an easy way to do that, is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no way to do this**. (As per `iOS 10`).

You can only **add URL** to safari using [SSReadingList](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/ssreadinglist) object using [SafariServices](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices)  but won't be able to read from it as that might comprise user privacy